# Can't bind value to ngModel in p-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have component , where I use primeNG `p-autocomplete`

Here is html of this component

```
<form #addressForm="ngForm" novalidate name="AddressForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Line1">{{ 'AddressLine1' | localize }} *</label>
    <p-autoComplete
        #addressLine1="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="address.line1"
        [suggestions]="addresses"
        field="name"
        [inputStyle]="{ width: '100%' }"
        name="lin1"
        (completeMethod)="searchAddress($event)"
        [size]="10"
        placeholder="{{ 'Line1Placeholder' | localize }}"
        (onSelect)="onSelectAddress($event)"
        [minLength]="3"
        required
        (change)="checkValidity()"
    ></p-autoComplete>
    <validation-messages [formCtrl]="addressLine1"></validation-messages>
  {{address.line1}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Line2">{{ 'AddressLine2' | localize }}</label>
    <input
        id="Line2"
        class="form-control"
        #line2Input="ngModel"
        type="text"
        name="Line2"
        placeholder="{{ 'Line2Placeholder' | localize }}"
        [(ngModel)]="address.line2"
        maxlength="128"
        (change)="checkValidity()"
    />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Line3">{{ 'AddressLine3' | localize }} </label>
    <input
        id="Line3"
        class="form-control"
        #line3Input="ngModel"
        type="text"
        name="Line3"
        [(ngModel)]="address.line3"
        maxlength="128"
        (change)="checkValidity()"
    />
    <validation-messages [formCtrl]="line3Input"></validation-messages>
</div>
```

and here is typescript part of component

```
 import { Component, Injector, forwardRef, ViewChild, AfterContentChecked, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { AddressType } from '@shared/AppEnums';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/common/app-component-base';
import { AddressDto } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';
import PlaceResult = google.maps.places.PlaceResult;
import { Feature } from '../../dto/mapboxOutput';
import { MapboxServiceService } from '../mapbox-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'edit-main-address',
    templateUrl: './edit-main-address.component.html',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: EditMainAddressComponent, multi: true },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditMainAddressComponent),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class EditMainAddressComponent extends AppComponentBase implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterContentChecked {
    @ViewChild('addressForm') addressForm;
    @ViewChild('search') public searchElement: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('postCode') public postCodeElement: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('town') public townElement: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('country') public countryElement: ElementRef;
    required: string | boolean;

    private changed = [];
    private touched = [];

    public selectedAddress: PlaceResult;
    disabled: boolean;
    address: AddressDto = new AddressDto();
    addressTypes: SelectItem[] = [];
    addresses: any[] = [];
    selectedAddresses: any = null;
    public lat: any;
    public lng: any;
    public postCode: string;
    public country: string;
    public city: string;
    public line1: any;

    constructor(injector: Injector, private mapboxService: MapboxServiceService) {
        super(injector);
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Main'), value: AddressType.Main });
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Billing'), value: AddressType.Billing });
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Delivery'), value: AddressType.Delivery });
        this.addressTypes.push({ label: this.l('Address.Correspondence'), value: AddressType.Correspondence });
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        this.checkValidity();
    }

    checkValidity(): void {}

    get value(): AddressDto {
        return this.address;
    }

    set value(value: AddressDto) {
        if (this.address !== value) {
            this.address = value;
            this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.changed.push(fn);
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.touched.push(fn);
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }

    writeValue(obj: AddressDto): void {
        if (obj) {
            this.address = obj;
            this.checkValidity();
        }
    }

    validate(): ValidationErrors {
        if (!this.addressForm.valid) {
            return { message: 'custom error' };
        }
        return null;
    }

    registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
        this.checkValidity = fn;
    }

    searchAddress(event: any): any {
        const searchTerm = event.query.toLowerCase();
        if (searchTerm && searchTerm.length > 0) {
            this.mapboxService.addressSearch(searchTerm).subscribe((features: Feature[]) => {
                this.addresses = [...features.map(e => ({ name: e.place_name, id: e.place_name, feature: e }))];
            });
        } else {
            this.addresses = [];
        }
    }

   onSelectAddress(event: any): any {
    if (event.feature.id.startsWith('address')) {
        this.address.line1 = event.name;
        this.address.longitude = event.feature.center[0];
        this.address.latitude = event.feature.center[1];
        this.address.postTown = event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('place')
        )[0].text;
        this.address.county = event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('district')
        )[0].text;
        this.address.country = event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('country')
        )[0].text;
        this.address.postCode = event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('postcode')
        )[0].text;
    }
    if (event.feature.id.startsWith('postcode')) {
        this.address.line1 = event.name;
        this.address.longitude = event.feature.center[0];
        this.address.latitude = event.feature.center[1];
        this.address.postTown =event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('place')
        )[0].text;
        this.address.county = event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('district')
        )[0].text;
        this.address.country = event.feature.context.filter(element =>
            element.id.startsWith('country')
        )[0].text;
        this.address.postCode = event.feature.text;
    }
}
    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

My problem is all fields with ngModel set great, but p-autocomplete is not setted

but if I wrote `{{address.line1}}` under input, all okay. You can see it from the screenshot.
[image]

Where can be my trouble, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You search addresses with searchAddress() which fills the addresses property.
Addresses are complex objects not simple strings, right?

```
 [suggestions]="addresses"
 (completeMethod)="searchAddress($event)"
 [(ngModel)]="address.line1"
```

so the ngModel of the p-autocomplete will be the selected address object. 
but then you bind ngModel to address.line1 which is expected to be a string.
Furthermore the address.line1 is then filled by the onSelectAddress method:

```
this.address.line1 = event.name;
```

I recommend you separate the selected address object from the address.line1 and bind the ngModel to a different property - say [(ngModel)]="selectedAddress"

Comment: the problem here is that when I open modal (HTML is part of modal) I try to set the value to `p-autocomplete` in `set` 

like this `set value(value: AddressDto) {
        if (this.address !== value) {
            this.address = value;
            this.selectedAddresses = value.line1;
            this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
        }
    }`

and this not works.

But for others, works well

Comment: Btw I changed to `[(ngModel)]="selectedAddress"` like you told

Comment: I hope my answer gives you the right direction, you need to investigate more. In the code above `this.selectedAddresses = value.line1` is wrong.
Please vote up or accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

if after @PeterFromCologne 's solution it's still not working make sure [multiple] is set to false

```
               <p-autoComplete
                  [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
                  [(ngModel)]="selectedLabTemplate.testName"
                  [suggestions]="selectedLabTemplate"
                  (completeMethod)="GetLabTest($event)"

                  [multiple]="false"
                ></p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you please articulate it better? And explain the reason for that change and what and how it's going to change the outcome?

Comment: For me, if you are assigning a value in ts file it was not getting binded to the p-autocomplete and it as happening as the multiple was set to true which means the p-autocomplete was expecting multiple values so was unable to bind a single value